# Install mdadm without postfix in ubuntu trusty

Tags: ubuntu, apt, postfix, mdadm

I want to build a RAID system on top of Ubuntu Trusty. When I do `apt-get install mdadm` A screen pop up asking me to configure postfix.

Because I will run this installation in automation script. Is there any way I can skip installing postfix or at least set to no-configuration in the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mdadm` package recommends a MTA so as to send an email if a disk fails. It's a useful feature, so I recommend that you do ensure that email is working.

Postfix is overkill for a system that does nothing but send emails to a relay. I recommend adding [`nullmailer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nullmailer) to your list of packages, and configure it appropriately.

Since you're doing an automated installation, you should use the [preseed](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html) feature.

Answer (score 5):

[neofug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/165834/neofug)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277664/install-mdadm-without-postfix-in-ubuntu-trusty#comment482617_277669) works more generally, in the case where you want to install `mdadm` without an MTA at all:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install mdadm
```

This won't pull in `postfix` or any other MTA. As the other answers suggest though, if you can configure your system to send an email when things go wrong, it's better to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can pre-seed the selections using `debconf-set-selections`

```
    debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/mailname string your.hostname.com"
    debconf-set-selections <<< "postfix postfix/main_mailer_type string 'Local Only'"
    apt-get install -y postfix
```

Appendix B. Automating the installation using preseeding :
https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/apbs03.html.en

Postfix configuration options :
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

Comment: Alternatively if you have a MTA installed and configured already you could run `apt-get --no-install-recommends install mdadm`